# Nginx - Varnish - Apache2: 301 redirects using map?

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

Nginx is listening ports 443 and 80, and redirecting everything from 80 to 443. Requests will go to Varnish port 8080 and after that to Apache2 using port 81. That works perfectly.

Now all 301s are done in Apache2, but then a request would go through Varnish to Apache2 and then after redirecting back to Varnish until we know if there is a hit or miss. I was thinking it is wiser to do directings in the beginning using map at Nginx using. But it isn't redirecting anything using map.

I have feeling I can't achieve that because of proxy-things (or something) and I have to use Apache2 and confs of virtual hosts there. But I can't ne sure because after several hours googling all I found is questions and tips of SSL redirects.

My setup (all domains and urls are real)

Virtual host of Nginx:

```
map_hash_bucket_size 256;

map $request_uri $new_uri {
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/includes/301.katiska.info.map;
    }

server {
        listen 46.101.98.116:443 ssl http2;
        server_name katiska.info www.katiska.info;

        access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log    /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        if ($new_uri != "") {
        #   rewrite ^ $new_uri permanent;
        #   rewrite ^(.*)$ $new_uri permanent;
            return 301 $new_uri;
        }

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/katiska.info/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/katiska.info/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    listen 46.101.98.116:80;
    server_name katiska.info www.katiska.info;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/katiska.info.access-80.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/katiska.info.error-80.log;

    if ($host = www.katiska.info) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    if ($host = katiska.info) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    return 404;

}
```

conf for map in location /etc/nginx/snippets/forwards/301.katiska.info.map:
(I'm using three different types of regex, very simple ones and as I know they should be right)

```
/kokeet /;
/koprofagia/?$ /terveys/terveys-yleinen/koprofagia/;
/koulutukset/$ /tag/kurssi/;
```

I don't put Varnish related here because I don't think those are relevant. Same with virtual hosts in Apache. Those work anyway and are very basics ones.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Richard knew and the problem is solved. Thanks.

So, redirect must begin with ~ (when a match is case-sensitive). This works:

```
~/kokeet /;
~/koprofagia/?$ /terveys/terveys-yleinen/koprofagia/;
~/koulutukset/$ /tag/kurssi/;
```

Totally different issue is that (almost) every web-page and answers here don't use ~ or ~*. Good  example why out there should be careful...

Comment: Your regular expressions need to start with a `~`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

Comment: None of Google hits aren't using it. I had it in the beginning but it didn't work either. But... there could be something else wrong then so I can't be sure... I've tried a lot of different things.

I'll give a try anyway.